# Adding a counter as index of the Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, counter

The code below takes a folder with xml files and parses them into a single csv file.
It does the job really good.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
from collections import defaultdict
import csv
from pathlib import Path

directory = 'C:/Users/docs/FolderwithXMLs'

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    headers = ['id', 'service_code', 'rational', 'qualify', 'description_num', 'description_txt', 'set_data_xin', 'set_data_xax', 'set_data_value', 'set_data_x']

    writer.writerow(headers)

    xml_files_list = list(map(str,Path(directory).glob('**/*.xml')))
    for xml_file in xml_files_list:
        tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
        root = tree.getroot()

        start_nodes = root.findall('.//START')
        for sn in start_nodes:
            row = defaultdict(str)


            for k,v in sn.attrib.items():
                row[k] = v

            for rn in sn.findall('.//Rational'):
                row['rational'] = rn.text

            for qu in sn.findall('.//Qualify'):
                row['qualify'] = qu.text

            for ds in sn.findall('.//Description'):
                row['description_txt'] = ds.text
                row['description_num'] = ds.attrib['num']


            for st in sn.findall('.//SetData'):
                for k,v in st.attrib.items():
                    row['set_data_'+ str(k)] = v
                row_data = [row[i] for i in headers]
                writer.writerow(row_data)
                row = defaultdict(str)
```

The output looks like this

[image]

I have been trying to add a counter for the numbers of how many rows of **set_data_value** for that specific ID there are.
The output should look like this

[image]

If necessary I can provide the xml data also. I am sorry someone has to edit the question to show the pictures instead of just hypelink

I have checked other posts here but I wasn't able to implement into this code

Comment: likely `df.groupby('id').cumcount().` Though you may first need to do `df['id'] = df['id'].ffill()`

Comment: @ALollz, would really appreciate if you could give it as an answer and maybe edit my question to show the picture so it is helpful for other users that might get the same question. thanks a lot

Comment: @ALollz  thank you for editing the question. Can you please help me with this one. if it is necessary I can put also the xml file

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the XML it will be a bit if a guess, but if you add "Counter" to `headers` and then add enumerate on the last for loop it may work

```
            for counter, st in enumerate( sn.findall('.//SetData') ):
                for k,v in st.attrib.items():
                    row['set_data_'+ str(k)] = v
                row["Counter"] = counter 
                row_data = [row[i] for i in headers]
                writer.writerow(row_data)
                row = defaultdict(str)
```

Comment: Can you please have a look at this question here. it is the same code as the one you helped me here. Would really appreciate it [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59955014/replacing-comma-on-xml-to-csv-parser?noredirect=1#comment106029185_59955014)