# Replacing comma on XML to CSV Parser

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm only going to include the part of the code that I’m trying to implement a new feature

```
for counter, st in enumerate( sn.findall('.//SetData') ):
    for k,v in st.attrib.items():
        if v.startswith("-"):      #If a string starts with - it removes it
            v = v.replace("-","",1)
        row['set_data_'+ str(k)] = v
    row["Counter"] = counter        #just a counter in another column
    row_data = [row[i] for i in headers]
    writer.writerow(row_data)
    row = defaultdict(str)
```

One of the elements that is being parsed has decimals numbers that are separated by a comma and not a dot and thus making them a string

So instead when the element is being parsed I wanted the values to be parsed like this `55,4` instead  `55.4`

When the numbers are separated by dot they are still integers which makes it easier for further use.

Comment: Replace the comma with a dot and cast as integer.

Comment: @Mayowa Ayodele, can you please elaborate more on how to integrate that into the code

Answer (score 0):

you can parse the number according to you locale settings.

```
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'danish')

s = '1.237,5'
locale.atof(s)
```

this will parse the string `s` to a float with value `1237.5`

To list available locales use: `locale.locale_alias`